# Запуск задачи андроид

Tags: android

На сайте [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html?hl=ru) в разделе про запуск задачи написано следующее:

> пользователи должны иметь возможность выходить из задачи и затем
>   возвращаться в нее с помощью этого средства запуска операции. Поэтому
>   два режима запуска, которые отмечают, что операции всегда инициируют
>   задачу, "singleTask" и "singleInstance", должны использоваться только
>   в тех случаях, когда операция содержит ACTION_MAIN и фильтр
>   CATEGORY_LAUNCHER. Представьте, например, что может произойти, если
>   фильтр отсутствует: намерение запускает операцию "singleTask", которая
>   инициирует новую задачу, и пользователь некоторое время работает в
>   этой задаче. Затем пользователь нажимает кнопку Домой. Задача
>   переводится в фоновый режим и не отображается. Теперь у пользователя
>   нет возможности вернуться к задаче, так как она отсутствует в средстве
>   запуска приложения.

Но ведь после нажатия на кнопку Домой, когда задача переводится в фоновый режим и не отображается, её можно вызвать из списка последних задач (или, иначе, из экрана обзора). Почему здесь написано, что "теперь у пользователя
нет возможности вернуться к задаче"?..